# Finding the longest word from a list of words

Tags: scala, collections

I have a list of words (with repetitions), and I intend to find out the longest words amongst them, along with their length. My question is to know if my implementation is too verbose, is using too many operators/functions and if so, what are the better, more idiomatic, readable alternatives.

Given the list below, the expected output is

> ```
>  Max length=3, words are "mnp","pqr","jkl","abc","xyz"
> ```

```
    val line = List("a","ab","abc","xyz","mnp","ac","d","b","ab","bc","bd","be","bf","b","abc","abc","pqr","mnp","jkl","a","b")

    val lengthAndTheWords = line.map(x => (x.length,x)).groupBy(x => x._1).mapValues(x => x.toSet)
    val longest = lengthAndTheWords.toSeq.sortBy(key => -key._1).head

    println("Max length =" + 
            longest._1 +
            ", words are" + 
            longest._2.map(nextEntry => nextEntry._2).mkString(","))
```

(With an [Ideone running the code](http://ideone.com/oRDqdW))

I consider myself an intermediate level Scala programmer; so, I am looking for all tips to improve my skills in Scala.

Comment: Does your example word list consist of string literals?

Comment: I edited an "s" out: "along with their lengths" -> "along with their length".  I am guessing you want the longest word(s) with its(their) length.

Comment: What's `xyz`? What's `pqr`? etc. As it currently stands, this code is a bit invalid.

Comment: This code is incomplete, and does not produce a result. It creates a map, but does not select the longest 'anything'.

Comment: @rolfl - I have edited the post following your comments. I have mentioned explicitly what is the expected output for the given input set. Thanks for your comments. Can this question now be taken off the hold please?

Comment: Nirmalya - you have doubled the amount of code since I commented, and the new code actually includes logic to actually find the longest words. Your code was not compiling because you were missing parenthesis. This all indicates to me that this code is not code that runs for you, and is just something you typed in to the Code Review box without running it. I have done that now for you by making the working ideone. Code Review requires real code from working projects.

Comment: @rolfl, I can't paste the real code from working projects, for obvious reasons. I don't know if that is expected either. I assure you that the code I have written here, reflects the exact logic that I am using in my project. My question has been about making the code better than what I have put in here. Thanks for your comment but I have been looking for tips to improve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever I only use the extracted value once in a simple group / map / sortBy monadic operations I use the `_` placeholders.  I think it makes the code a little more compact and readable, especially if it was just a placeholder value like `x`

`.groupBy(x => x._1)` becomes `.groupBy(_._1)`

`.mapValues(x => x.toSet)` becomes `.mapValues(_.toSet)` or even `mapValues toSet` if you like infix

It's not a universal rule by any means, sometimes you really need a meaningful name so that another coder could make sense of it.

**Edit**
Also you can go straight to the group by and remove redundant counts

```
val oneLiner = line.groupBy(_.length).mapValues(_.toSet).maxBy(_._1)

//> oneLiner  : (Int, scala.collection.immutable.Set[String]) = (3,Set(abc, pqr, mnp, jkl, xyz))
```

Comment: thanks for the one-liner. I always felt that mine was verbose. As for the placeholder '_', I prefer to put a parameter explicitly because it helps me to 'see' the function logic somewhat clearly, but that is primarily due to my (slowly receding) unease about the functional idioms. Many thanks.

Comment: I think Odersky was real smart to leave both ways in there so that there's an option that's not off-putting to beginners.  The more I went down the rabbit hole I preferred the placeholders.